# PC gets restart on running android studio emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have installed andriod studio 3.6 latest version and then configured by setting environment variables.

When i actually run virtual device Pixel 3 emulator, my PC ran in to problem with blue screen.

```
Blue screen error message: 
Your PC ran into a problem and needs to restart. Were just collecting some error info, and then you can restart.
```

How to resolve this ? what is the problem ?

Comment: Sounds like you ran out of memory. How much ram does your computer have?

Comment: Add your PC configuration: RAM, processor, free space in C drive, etc. As @HB. mentioned, it must be mostly an out of memory scenario

Comment: Computer has 16GB RAM. @HB

Answer (score 2):

Just remove from windows features:

1. HyperV
2. Virtual Machine Platform
3. Windows HyperVisor Platform

Install:

Intel(R) Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM)

Answer (score 1):

Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator(HAXM) solved my problem

Comment: Yes, this fixed the blue screen error `VIDEO_TDR_FAILURE` on my end.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and spend a lot of time trying to solve it. Finally find what was the problem - Windows update!
This Windows patches are causing the problem - KB4554354 and KB4549949

Updating the Windows to version 1909 (OS build 18363.836) fix the issue for me.

If you can't update windows to this version for some reason you can try to remove this patches.
You can rollback and uninstall your recent update follow these Steps:

1. Press Start button then click on the Gear icon which is the Settings
2. Press "Update and Security"
3. Press "View Update History"
4. Select "Uninstall Updates"
5. A pop up should appear then scroll down to the bottom then on the Microsoft Windows section, right click the recent or all of the "Update for Microsoft Windows KB4554354" then Click "uninstall".
6. wait for the process to be finished then restart the PC/Laptop there you should have the fix on your update problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is just to share my experience that the blue screen has stopped for me too, by updating Windows 10 to the version 1909.

Though it is not talked about here, I have the impression that it is related to the Microsoft's Hyper-V and the Windows Hypervisor Platform (WHPX), made available in the year 2018.

For me, the emulator was working till late last year, without the Hyper-V acceleration (I cannot be more precise. I do not use it everyday).

Earlier this year, I installed the Docker desktop, which must have turned on Hyper-V. The Windows update(s) may have come around the time (though I do not find them here. They may be part of one of the cumulative patches). Then it must have become that the emulator wouldn't work anymore.

Hope it helps others who suffer from the same problem.

Answer (score -2):

i think the emulator is not working properly ......uninstall the current emulator and install trusted emulators like blue stacks ........blue stacks will work in old pc's also